# Formerly email validation

Tags: plugins-formerly

What is the correct Validation Pattern format to add to a Formerly email field in the Craft admin control panel if I want to stop any submissions from email addresses with a .ru TLD?

I've tried:

```
!(\.ru)
/^((?!\.ru).)*$/s
```

But they do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try find the regex string in https://regex101.com/ where you can define your pos and neg examples.

.*(?:(?!ru).).$

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it doesn't work

Comment: My code is pure regex code, it should probably be converted to php. Try add delimiters  /.*(?:(?!ru).).$/mu

Comment: Yes, the problem is probably with the plugin that I am trying to use, I dont know what the format should be, or how it is supposed to work, and there doesn't appear to be any documentation